# EasyMock: Add one more expectation after replay

Tags: java, easymock

Is it possible to add expectation after having mock object  replayed?

Comment: As @Tom says, you can reset the mock but it might be helpful to give more context to the larger problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Mock object is defined and configured in parent abstract class. I receive it in my chuld class and want to add some expectations. Reset will clear the stack.

Comment: Why do you have to call replay before your child class receives it?

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to reset a mock object and apply new expectations to it before replaying it again.

```
EasyMock.reset(myMock)
```

See the [EasyMock documentation](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html) for more information.

Comment: Mock object is defined and configured in parent abstract class. I receive it in my chuld class and want to add some expectations. Reset will clear the stack.

Comment: In which case, the answer is no. Perhaps you could define a method in the abstract class that returns the mock with its expectations set up but not in replay mode. You could then call this from your subclass and add the expectations. Alternatively, the abstract superclass could call an abstract method which you override.